# How can I log in to Stack Exchange using email if my account was created by Facebook?

Tags: discussion, email

I have Stack Exchange account that was created using Facebook.

Now I use Windows Parental Controls to block sites (i.e. Facebook), and I can’t log into Stack Exchange.

There is an option in Stack Exchange to log in using an email.

But I can’t see in logged in user account in “Edit Profile & Settings” and “My Logins” and ”add more logins…” an option to add email. There are only more Facebook, Google+ like options.

How can I log in to Stack Exchange using email if my account was created by facebook?

Comment: You really should check meta SE.. This is probably asked and answered there already.

Answer (score 2):

> But I can’t see in logged in user account in “Edit Profile & Settings”
>   and “My Logins” and ”add more logins…” an option to add email. There
>   are only more Facebook, Google+ like options.

If you click on the “add more logins…” then the way you could create an email only account is to simply create a Stack Exchange account which would be a local system (as far as Stack Exchange goes) account that is bound to your email and password.

Just login using Facebook, then add a Stack Exchange login using the email of your choice and you’re good to go!

[image: Screenshot of the login management page.]